# GAE and IAP: frontend and backend in two containers?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, frontend, backend, identity, app-engine-ndb

I understand that both FE and BE can be run in the same container, placing one process in the background. This ways CORS issues are resolved and Identity Access Proxy is only called once when the app URL is visited.

Is it advisable to separate FE and BE into two separate containers? I think CORS could be resolved with headers, but IAP portal would be introduced twice? Once for each app?

Comment: Clarify what you mean by FE. The frontend runs in the client browser, not in the container. The frontend communicates to the backend typically using HTTP over a network (Internet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many aspect to your question.

Do you use containers? So why do you use GAE and not Cloud Run?

With GAE, you have the chance to have only one platform, one domain name and therefore you won't have CORS issues or IAP issue. It's homogeneous

---

With Cloud Run it's different. Because the URL will be different, you will have CORS issue. The simple way to solve that is to expose your web application (FE + BE) behind a load balancer and therefore with your own domain name.

IAP is not a concern, you can activate [IAP on Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-cloud-run) and it will work smoothly

But, if you are doing that (use Cloud Run + Load Balancer), I strongly recommend an hybrid deployment:

- Serve the frontend with App Engine (serving static files is free and up to 1Gb egress per day is included)
- Serve the BE with Cloud Run.
- Put a HTTP load balancer in front to unify the domain name and remove CORS issues
- Activate IAP. I tested this combination for my company, and it works perfectly: the browser reuse the IAP cookies got from the FE to inject them when it calls the BE